# symbol map in algebraic K theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

I have a smooth projective morphism $X \to S$ or relative dimension 1 (i.e.
a family of smooth curves over base $S$). There should be a map $H^2(X, K_2) \to H^1(S, K_1) = Pic(S)$ given by integration along the fibers (the cohomology is in the Zariski topology and $K_i$ are the Zariski sheaves of algebraic $K$-theories). In other words, some kind of global version of the symbol map in $K$-theory.

Is this written up somewhere? The only thing I have seen is a paper by Brylinsky and someone else, where they take two rational functions $f$ and $g$ and cook up a number, froom values of $f$ at zeros and poles of $g$, and values of $g$ at zeros and poles of $f$.

Comment: You probably already know this, but in case not: If $S$ is a smooth variety over any field then $H^2(X,K_2)$ is isomorphic to $CH^2(X)$  ("Bloch's formula") and the map you want is then presumably just the pushforward map on Chow groups.

Comment: Yes, but I need S to be arbitrary. Is there a relative Gersten complex? 